# ImportError: Using the Trainer with PyTorch requires accelerate = 0.20.1

Tags: python, pytorch, artificial-intelligence, google-colaboratory, huggingface-transformers

Please help me when I tried to use it in my Google Colab for transformers

error:

> ImportError: Using the Trainer with PyTorch requires
> accelerate=0.20.1: Please run pip install transformers[torch] or pip
> install accelerate -U`

NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.

transformers - GPT - pytorch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps:
pip install accelerate -U
then
Restart the notebook
run all
and you'll see it'll solve

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error in Colab with:

```
pip install transformers
from transformers import TrainingArguments
training_args = TrainingArguments(output_dir="test_trainer")
# ...
# ImportError: Using the `Trainer` with `PyTorch` requires `accelerate>=0.20.1`: Please run `pip install transformers[torch]` or `pip install accelerate -U`
```

What helped was:

```
!pip install transformers==4.28.0
```

(and restarting the runtime afterwards)

PS This was not my idea of course, credits go to: https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/cant-use-trainer-in-colab/50370/2